# Optional attribute binding

Tags: angular

I'm building a custom checkbox component that wraps a real `input` and makes it look stylish.

One requirement for my custom checkbox is being able to bind an **optional** name so that the checkbox can be submitted as part of a form.

```js
@Component({
    selector: 'my-checkbox'
    template: `
    <input type="checkbox" [name]="name">
    `
    /*, ...etc */
})
export class MyCheckbox implements ControlValueAccessor {
    @Input() name: string;

    // ...etc
}
```

Usage:

```
<!-- named-->
<my-checkbox [(ngModel)]="vm" name="coolcool"></my-checkbox>

<!-- unnamed-->
<my-checkbox [(ngModel)]="vm"></my-checkbox>
```

The output of the named example looks just fine

```html
<!-- named output -->
<my-checkbox>
    <input type="checkbox" name="coolcool">
</my-checkbox>
```

...but the output of the unnamed example also has a name attribute?!

```html
<!-- unnamed output -->
<my-checkbox>
    <input type="checkbox" name="undefined">
</my-checkbox>
```

How do I make `name="undefined"` go away?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can simply change the template inside the `MyCheckbox` 's template to this:

```
<input *ngIf="!(!name)" type="checkbox" [name]="name">
<input *ngIf="!name" type="checkbox">
```

**update:**

checked this, works with input and name:
 try changing the binding from `[name]="name"` to `[attr.name]="name"`  and see if it works.

Comment: I believe Angular does some magic when you bind a boolean to `[disabled]`. In plain html, `disabled` does not accept `true` or `false`, only `"disabled"` or an empty string.

Comment: exactly, but when i used it in this form: ```[disabled]="boolean? true: undefined"```, it worked. 
that aside, doesn't the use of *ngIf work for you?

Comment: It probably works because of that magic. It probably won't work with any other attribute.

I could use ngIf but that's not DRY code. In reality I have a whole bunch of other attributes that I don't want to repeat.

Comment: Actually just using `attr` was enough: `[attr.name]="name"`

Comment: I guess Angular is smart enough to ignore undefined when `[attr.name]="undefined"` but not when `[name]="undefined"`

Comment: all I had to do was change `[name]` to `[attr.name]` so if you remove the unneeded code from your answer then I can accept it.

Answer (score 19):

Hope this helps you

```
<input type="checkbox" [attr.name]="name?name :null">
```